# SELECT clause for 3 data fields and display as 1 field

Tags: sql, oracle

Table name : LOCATION

```
//LOCATION
CITY      ROAD#        STREET#
-------------------------------
ANSON      41           16
```

Following query:

```
SELECT (CITY,ROAD#,STREET#) AS "Location" FROM LOCATION;
```

hope to get following output like:

```
Location
----------------
ANSON,41,16
```

isn't possible to get something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CITY || ',' || ROAD# || ',' || STREET# AS "Location" FROM LOCATION;
```